# Count specific character in a string

Tags: java

I can't find a reason as to why `arr[i].charAt(word)` is not working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] arr = {"121", "333", "333"};
    int count = 0;
    int word = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (word = 0; word<arr[i].length(); word++) {
            if (arr[i].charAt(word) == 1) { //this line gives me trouble
                count++;
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why isnt it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`charAt` returns a `char`, so you need to put 1 in single quotes when comparing it as a `char` like so:

```
if(arr[i].charAt(word)== '1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not comparing a `char` to a `char`, you're comparing a `char` to an `int`. Which just happens to be legal because `char`s are numbers internally (put very simply, there's more to it than that of course).

Change the line to:

```
if(arr[i].charAt(word)== '1')
```

Notice the quotes.